# How to send email in custom plugin without installing any other plugin like "WP Mail SMTP"

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I am developing a plugin and i want to send email when insert query works .it is inserting data but email is not sending,I don't want to use any other plugin for this.I googled it, but  every solution they require a plugin for sending email i do not want any other plugin for this i want custom code in my plugin

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    /*echo $email;
    die; 
 Here email_send_plugin is Database custom table name
    */


if(!empty($email)){
    $insert = $wpdb->insert('email_send_plugin',
        array(
            'email'=>$email
        ));
    if(is_wp_error($insert)){
        echo "Failed to insert email";

    }
    else{
        echo "Email Inserted";
        $to = 'example@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'The subject';
        $body = 'The email body content';
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $email_status = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
    if($email_status){
        echo "A mail sent to user";

    }
    else{
        echo "Sending failed";

    }
    }

}
else{
    echo "Email field is required";

}



}



 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which you can insert to your theme's functions.php

```
remove_action('phpmailer_init', 'swpsmtp_init_smtp');    
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'custom_phpmailer_init' );
function custom_phpmailer_init( PHPMailer $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Host = 'HOSTNAME_HERE';
    $phpmailer->Port = 465; //or different  
    $phpmailer->Username = 'USERNAME_HERE'; 
    $phpmailer->Password = 'PASS_HERE'; 
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';//or tls
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();
}
function website_email() {
    $sender_email= 'YOURSENDEREMAIL_HERE';
    return $sender_email;
}
add_filter('wp_mail_from','website_email');
```

So if just to give correct values for hostname, port, username, password, sender email and security parameters, it will start working without any problem.

Comment: Okk i wil try this thanks for answering but i want to use in plugin file can i insert this function in my plugin file.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter

Comment: It is working fine on functions.php but not working on my plugin page

Comment: Just put it to the main file  bof your plugin, not to any other file. And don't put it inside any function or hook. Just put it f.e. to the bottom part of your plugin's mail file.  And make sure the plugin is active.